# How many answers are required to turn a question into Community Wiki on a beta site?

Tags: support, community-wiki, beta-sites

The [FAQ answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/1674430) says

> •The question generates more than **30** answers (**15** on Super User and Programmers, **60** on Code Golf). In this case, the question and all answers will enter community mode, as will any future answers.

Does the 30 threshold apply to beta sites, or is it 15? It looks like 15, based on [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9128/869), but that's not clearly stated anywhere.

Comment: It was 30 for [this question](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/11025/my-pre-schooler-is-out-of-control-and-i-feel-like-my-parents-are-undermining-my) on [Parenting](parenting.stackexchange.com), which is in beta.

Comment: The workplace probably has a custom limit that's not mentioned by FAQ.

Comment: @3ventic Workplace has custom limit announced at TWP meta: [Should we reduce the Community Wiki threshold to 10 answers?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1659/168) "I've dropped the threshold to 15. 10 seems dangerously low to me..."

Comment: @gnat well, there's the answer then

Comment: @gnat Thanks, no idea why I didn't think to look there first.

Comment: This is determined on a site-by-site basis.

Currently, [the threshold on The Workplace is 15](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1659/869).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previously, there were sites that had different thresholds. I believe it was Programmers, Super User, and Workplace that had a lower threshold at 15, while some specific places had higher thresholds of 60, 200, and in one exceedingly odd case 300. We're still not sure why that one had that high. Maybe it was a typo of 30, haha. ♪

As of today, though, **there are actually no thresholds existing anymore**. Posts will no longer be converted to community wiki when they receive a certain number of answers.

There are flags that will be raised when certain thresholds are met, and these thresholds are identical between graduated and beta sites. **Questions that receive 30 answers, or that receive 10 answers within 7 days, will receive flags for moderator attention**. This is, like its predecessor, site-specific. But the only exception currently is that **Code Golf has had the values increased to 100 and 30-in-7-days respectively.**